# Um cursor dentro de outro cursor sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Sei que poderia fazer um join de tab1 com o tab2, mas esse não seria o caso, preciso dos dois cursores.

Quando executo eu recebo o erro de:

```
A cursor with the name 'cursor_tab2 ' already exists.

The cursor is already open.
```

Eu até entendo o erro, mas não sei resolver.

Qual a maneira certa para se fazer isso?

Tenho usado.

```
DECLARE cursor_tab1 CURSOR
    FOR SELECT id FROM tab1
    OPEN cursor_tab1
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_tab1
    INTO @idTab1

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN


        DECLARE cursor_tab2 CURSOR
        FOR SELECT id FROM tab2 where id_tab1 = @idTab1
        OPEN cursor_tab2
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_tab2
        INTO @idTab2

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN

            ...


        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_tab2 INTO @idTab2;
        END



    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_tab1 INTO @idTab1;
    END
```

Comment: Por que você precisa de dois cursores?

Comment: Existe toda uma logica aí no meio, ela defini se eu vou ou não utilizar o segundo, mas depende de outros fatores, não é uma procedure simples... Coloquei o código básico para ficar mais fácil de perguntar e ler a resposta, acho que assim fica mais fácil para os próximos usuários que consultaresm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes de mais convém dizer que são poucos os problemas que necessitam de cursores para serem resolvidos em SQL.

Dito isto, aparentemente não estás a fechar e libertar (dealocate) os cursores.

```
CLOSE cursor_tab2
DEALLOCATE cursor_tab2
```

Caso estejas e não seja esse o problema então declara o cursor como LOCAL.

```
DECLARE teuCursor CURSOR LOCAL ...
```

Comment: perfeito. Coloquei o CLOSE e o DEALLOCATE e funcionou perfeitamente.